# Endless contribution forms

Tags: contributions, recurring-contributions

My customer has a donation page which with no end date but when registering a donation, it's telling him maximum 12 months.

he would like to create a donation page where the contribution will go on further than 12 months until the user actually cancel his recurrent contribution

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "it's telling him maximum 12 months." can you add screenshots. doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: and / or replicate on one of the demo sites

Comment: "You can specify the number of installments, or you can leave the number of installments blank if you want to make an open-ended commitment"